# Named outlet in lazy loaded module (angular 6.0.5)

Tags: angular

I thought this was fixed with angular 6 but either i'm missing something or fix is not complete.

This is the setup...in **app.routing:**

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'management',
        loadChildren: 'app/features/management/management.module#ManagementModule'
      }
    ]
  }
```

`LayerContainerComponent` just splits the view into header & content area.

in **management.routing**:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ManagementLayoutContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'someroute',
        component: SomeRouteContainerComponent,
        canActivate: [
          SomeGuard
        ]
      },
      {
         path: 'updatemodal',
         component: UpdateModalComponent,
         outlet: 'modal'
      }
   ]
}
```

`ManagementLayoutContainerComponent` contains one regular `router-outlet` and also `<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>`

on route `management/someroute` i have template with: `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { modal: 'updatemodal' } }]"`

Now, usecase:

1. navigate to `management/someroute`
2. click to link with given `routerlink` (above)
3. error thrown:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'management/someroute'
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
>   (router.js:1359)

Basically, error says that it cannot match route on which it already is!

Now, when i hover that link, url seems correct: `/management/someroute/(modal:updatemodal)`

**Question:**
Am i missing something or is this still a problem in angular?

Comment: I thought it wasn't working at first with my routes but it seemed like it might be very specific about the outlet's relation to the tree of the main path.. you might want to try links like "['/management', {outlets:{modal:'updatemodal'}}]" and using a navigate from within a function to get to the right paths which worked for me when a routerlink initially did not... I think there must be some logic to how outlets work to the relative path but it is definitely underspecified in the current documentation.

Comment: thanks for your input! didn't work unfortunately. btw, did you get it to work from lazy loaded module?

Comment: I could not get a lazy loaded outlet working on the root and used a local component, but later I changed a nested path in my lazy loaded module to use a named outlet and afa I remember it did work if I was careful about the link.. I was tending to get errors where it was clearly building nested subroutes before I found the right combination of an explicit path and the subroute to modify if I recall correctly.. I don't have the code here unfortunately.

Comment: That's odd, 6.0.5 should of fixed that, based on this commit which was merged to 6.0.5: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5731d0741ab418772b31548ec7a89305fe7d813c

Comment: testing against my app you would need a mainpath and something like ['..', { outlets: { modal: 'updatemodal' } }] would work from someroute, no main path is trying to route to an outlet under 'someroute' for me.

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[routerLink]="[ '', { outlets: { modal: 'updatemodal' } }]`